# Calculate EXIF Data Apex Values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, photo, exif

I'm trying to calculate the Aperture values from some some images using JavaScript, the values are pulled from the images EXIF data and are in APEX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEX_system format.

This doc, http://dougkerr.net/Pumpkin/articles/APEX.pdf under appendix A seems to show the formula required for Aperture and Shutter speed, but i'm having a hard time translating it to JavaScript.

I know that aperture Apex value 1.5 should equal 1.7, and 3.0 should equal 2.8 etc,  but im just not getting correct answers back.

Here's a quick fiddle, the formula is all wrong though. 
http://jsfiddle.net/41zm7os7/1/

```
var apexVal = 3.0; //This should convert to 2.8
var aperture = 2 * Math.log2(apexVal)
```

Should be 
[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: post your code or create a jsfiddle

Comment: i don't think an apex value alone is enough info to determine both, though with ts or av and the apex zone (and ISO), you could determine the other. to wit, `1/10th@f2` and `1/5th@f1.4` would record the same apex on a given iso. that said, EXIF usually has shutter speed and aperture info, the meta's apex is probably the base light level that auto-exposure used to select the exposure variables.

Comment: Yep, it has all those values , but it should be enough to just calculate the f/ number right?   If I wasnt trying to calc the shutter speed at the same time

Comment: updated original post

Comment: you can't calc Ts or Av from APEX alone. APEX is a combination of the two. you could find possible combinations of the two, ala the "sunny 16" rule, but you can't deductively solve two unknown factors.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around, because 2 * log2 (2.8) = 2.97 and 2 * log2 (1.5) = 1.699

Comment: Hah.. yes, I think you're right m69. It is the otherway around.  So, dumb question, how do I reverse that when I don't know the number that's going to be passed into the log2 function?  ... thats the number I need to calculate - eg,  f/20 is 8.6 -  and,  2 * Math.log2(20) = 8.6

Comment: I think that's N = 2 ^ (An / 2), but it's been a while since I last worked with this kind of math :-)

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look quite right.   Example using 8.6 again (which should come out roughly to 20) it comes out as 6.  -->    2 ^ (8.6 / 2)

Comment: Yea, I have a mapping of some static numbers and what I know their converted values to be.  It's been pretty reliable so far, but I need to calculate them on the fly now hence why I know that 8.6 should end up as roughly 20 (rounded up) etc.   It looks like we had the formula working before with:   2 * Math.log2(20) = 8.6   I just don't know how to reverse that to figure out the 20

Comment: Well, 2 ^ (8.6 / 2) = 19.7 ~ 20. (You thought the result was 6, but I think you mistyped on your calculator or something)

Comment: Sure? What am I doing wrong here.   see here http://jsfiddle.net/w2og2k0k/

Comment: Try Math.pow(2, (8.6 / 2)). In javascript, ^ is XOR.

Comment: Bingo .. You got it, that's enough for me to work with :)  Awesome, thanks man..  Post this as an answer and i'll check it off as answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That formula will turn 2.8 into 3. Apparently you need the inverse of that formula, i.e. N = 2 ^ (An / 2).

```
 var apexVal = 3.0; //This should convert to 2.8
 var aperture = Math.pow(2, apexVal / 2);
```